# Detecting if popup was dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 2 views in my storyboard: a view, then a popup view. What i want to happen is when the user finishes filling out the information on the popup, and pressed the close, for the original view controller to detect if the popup was dismissed. I hope this makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: You need to implement a delegate in popup view to pass data to original view controller, you can find more information about how implement delegates [here](https://medium.com/compileswift/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef#.906jkllrt)

Comment: Its in objective-c, not swift

Comment: Your question's title and body don't really match. If your actual goal is more like your title then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: Don't detect that the popup was dismissed.  Detect that your model changed.

Comment: I dont understand, Im really new to programing

Comment: Your question is way too vague and general, forcing us to _guess_ what you are doing in order to answer, which is ridiculous. Stack Overflow is about actual programming. Show, and provide context for, _the actual code_ by which (1) the popup view is made to appear, and (2) the close button responds.